Python Logger is not writing to console and logFile
I have issue with logger which I created in my Project.
I am using python 3.11.9
I need to write to console messages from INFO level higher and to LogFile from DEBUG level.
Script is running correctly, but console and log outputs are empty.
I looked on Stack for many other questions and tried some thing like removing name from getLogger and check my syntax but nothing is working.
Does anyone has some idea where can be problem ?
Here is my log_handler():
def log_handler():
    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    _logger = logging.getLogger()

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

    _logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    log_dir = Path(Path('.').absolute(), 'logfile.txt')

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_dir)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

    _logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return _logger

class myApp(myAppExceptions):
    def __init__(self):
         self.logger = log_handler()


self.logger.info('message')





Maybe check the levels of the loggers. How are you executing the app? pytest for example does some configurations with the root logger which might interfere.

I am running script via in main via HS.run(), in this case HS is instance created from my main class. For testing I am using basic unittest library, but this issue I have even on regular script run. Levels should be ok. I though that there can be some issue but in my case nothing with self.logger is not written in output.

Well, at least in your snippet you're not setting any log level of the logger itself. And in default case the root logger (which you are retrieving) has WARNING as log level. So, are you 100% sure, that this is not the problem?

The issue with your code is that the root logger (logging.getLogger()) is being used, but its default log level is WARNING, which means that messages with a level lower than WARNING (such as INFO or DEBUG) won't be displayed.
To ensure that all log messages are shown, you need to set the log level of the root logger to DEBUG. Here's the updated code:
def log_handler():
  log_format = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')

  _logger = logging.getLogger()
  _logget.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
  console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
  console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

  _logger.addHandler(console_handler)

  log_dir = Path(Path('.').absolute(), 'logfile.txt')

  file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_dir)
  file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

  _logger.addHandler(file_handler)
  return _logger

class myApp(myAppExceptions):
    def __init__(self):
         self.logger = log_handler()
         self.logger.info('message')

